# How to insert result set stored in SSIS variable into a table in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreach, ssis, etl

I have to take a result set generated from a query in a database in one server, and insert that into a table in another database in another server. I can't do this using a Linked Server as the DBA does not have it set up and will not set it up either. So I'm forced to use SSIS to do this. I have gotten to the point where I am storing the result set generated from the query into an object variable. This is the query to get the result set below.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM dbo.SFprod_Application a
WHERE RECORDTYPEID = '0122L000000kDXZQA2'
ORDER BY ETL_ID DESC;
```

I have the data generated from that query in a variable with Result Name 0 and Variable Name `User::LoadApplication`.

I am unsure how to take the result set that is stored in this variable, and insert it into a table in SQL Server. For example I would like to take the results stored in that variable and insert into a table called `dbo.FApplication` that is in database `A1` in server `A2`.

The destination table is configured with the correct columns and data types needed to store the result set. I just don't know how to get that from the variable into the target table. I have seen some mention of using for each loop containers and maybe C# code. I am fairly new to SSIS, so I'm not very familiar with C# or foreach containers. Any help showing how to use those properly would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: so far so good and it CAN be done via object variable, BUT is there any reason why you don't use a regular `DATA FLOW` in SSIS?

Comment: Please check [the following article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/) for examples how to use Object Variable and ForEach Loop. Please note that you have to know each column in SELECT statement, so using wildcard `a.*` can work if you do know functions of 1st, 2nd and the other rows.

Comment: @Tyron78 is correct. You want a data flow task here. While what you're attempting is possible with a loop, it is the least efficient way to do it, other than hand typing the data.